# System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content("~/Assets/Images/" + String.Format(fileName)); does not work the same in IE 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-10

We have a helper method to let us easlily get access to files in our Assets/Images folder

for a weird reason there is an html file there, which is in essence referred to thusly

```
System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper();
return helper.Content("~/Assets/Images/" + String.Format("file.htm"));
```

IN ie 7, 8, & 9 this correctly resolves to the assets/images folder.

The IT group just started upgrading boxes to IE10, and now when run on and IE10 (which we never tested) I get this error when the code is called.

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\IIS Web Services &
>   Apps\Application(F(7-lOGKlgR_6Zt3F_ngapPUyhSkzYn6260oMMNwpok0HNB2VLinboD_2zHXiYCJUFPQ2ADaQP14ShDe5_KiRx9J5JtNOL-9UQCLQoDBjhz1Pj6pSJjZcHQ2dg8lBHadwHxlxJjVbxtBeLL125sIZaIafjFzg4g-ZX2Kr6C72TTd7RQFL70))\Assets\Images\file.htm'.

and to make it better, it's only happening on the production servers, not on my development box.

Does anyone have any ideas for a work around?
Any other big IE 10 Gotchas we should be looking for?

Comment: I see the IIS error, but what precisely is the browser interpreting as the URL in the href/src attribute?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't reproduce the error in develoment, only in production. So the error is all i have to work on at the moment. IS there are foolproof microsoft MVC way to get the path to a file in assets\images, no matter what mode MS asp.net MVC is working in... it sure seems like there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

That big ugly string in the path variable you referenced appears to the the session Id which IIS/.NET will default to putting in the URL if your browser will not accept cookies or if cookieless sessions are turned on.

I would check

- IIS and your web.config for items concerning SessionState and FormsAuthentication and the use of cookies.
- IE 10 security settings: it may work on your dev machine since "localhost" would be in the trusted sites and most likely would allow cookies coming from there.